# Simple example of using FeaturesDlg in WIX

Tags: wix

The only documentation for the FeaturesDlg I can find on the WIX site is a brief two-line description. I'm finding lots of esoteric, advanced samples of how to attempt to do difficult things, customizations, etc. I just want to know how to use it in the most simple, basic, easy way. I have four features, and I want the user to be able to choose which of them to install. That's all. Can anyone point me to a simple example? Do I need to have a Publish element and manually control the entire sequence of dialogs in order to use the FeaturesDlg?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WixUI_FeatureTree` dialog set. See [Using Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html).

Comment: Thanks. I've been to that page, and I am wanting to use that, but I can't find any actual documentation or simple example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, all it took was to change the UIRef to this:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree"/>
```